# Matsubara Frequencies

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, path-integral

I have to evaluate the following [Matsubara sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency):

$$\frac1\beta \sum \left(\omega^2 +a^2\right)^{-1}$$ for Bosonic-Matsubara frequencies.

I know contour integration it the way to go. Therefore, I wrote:

$$\frac1\beta \sum \left[(\omega-ia)(\omega +ia)\right]^{-1} = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \times \int dz\, \left[(z-a)(z +a)\right]^{-1}g(z)$$

where

$$g(z)=-\frac12\tanh(\beta z /2).$$

My final result is therefore

$$\frac1{2a} \coth(\beta a/2).$$

Can someone tell me if this is correct or if I am wrong?  And moreover, are there rules/limitations for choosing $g(z)$?

Comment: I would suggest you read Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency) before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this Matsubara sum that only involves standard results is the following. First, write 
$$A=T\sum_n \frac{1}{\omega_n^2+a^2}=T\sum_n \frac{e^{i\omega_n 0^+}}{\omega_n^2+a^2},$$
where the convergent factor $e^{i\omega_n 0^+}$ can be added freely since the sum converges. From this
$$A=\frac{T}{2a}\sum_n \frac{e^{i\omega_n 0^+}}{i\omega_n+a}-\frac{T}{2a}\sum_n \frac{e^{i\omega_n 0^+}}{i\omega_n-a}.$$
Using the standard Matsubara sum (for $\omega_n=2\pi Tn$ )
$$T\sum_n \frac{e^{i \omega_n 0^+}}{i\omega_n-a}=-n(a),$$
with $n(a)$ the Bose function, as well as $n(-a)=-n(a)-1,$ we get
$$A=\frac{2n(a)+1}{2a}=\frac{\coth(\beta\, a/2)}{2a}.$$